# How to use an API key with Odoo17 in POSTMan

Tags: postman, odoo-17

I'm looking for a way to use an API key in Odoo 17 + PostMan. The documentation on Odoo is sparse an there is no 1 clear answer. I've spent almost 5hours of searching and there's no clear answer on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

I have a vanilla installation of Odoo 17 running on local at http://localhost:8069

I'm able to authenticate in POSTMan using basic auth:

`{{odoo-api}}/web/session/authenticate`

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "params": {
        "db" : "{{odoo-db}}",
        "login" : "{{odoo-username}}",
        "password" : "{{odoo-pwd}}"
    }
}
```

I'm NOT able to authenticate using POSTMan using

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "params": {
        "db" : "{{odoo-db}}",
        "login" : "{{odoo-username}}",
        "password" : "{{odoo-api-key}}"
    }
}
```

Some suggestions for using an api key has been to include an

- `api_key` header with value `{{apikey}}`
- `Authorization Bearer API_KEY` header with value `{{apikey}}`
- `API_KEY` header with value `{{apikey}}`

but I'm not having any success.

I'm expecting the typical application of an API key header with a header. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those were the responses from the Odoo forums. I figured the people on there would know what the answer would be, but I've yet to find a functioning example.